# LINQ Is it possible to get a method name without a return type via LINQ expression trees?

Tags: linq, tree, get, properties, expression

I know it is possible to retrieve a property name or a method with a return type. But is it also possible to get a method name without a return type via LINQ expression trees?

Example: string methodname = GetMethodname(x=>x.GetUser());

---> results: "GetUser"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely - but you'll want a method signature like this:

```
public static string GetMethodName<T>(Expression<Action<T>> action)
```

(That means you'll need to specify the type argument when you call it, in order to use a lambda expression.)

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Test
{
    void Foo()
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string method = GetMethodName<Test>(x => x.Foo());
        Console.WriteLine(method);
    }

    static string GetMethodName<T>(Expression<Action<T>> action)
    {
        MethodCallExpression methodCall = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodCall == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Only method calls are supported");
        }
        return methodCall.Method.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about getting a method name from a specified type? i.e. Expression<Func<TSource, Action<TTarget>>>?

Comment: @Shimmy: It's not really clear what you mean, to be honest. Might be worth a new question?

Comment: I want this function: `static MethodInfo GetMethod(Expression<Func<TTarget, EventHandler<TEventArgs>>> method)`, [here](http://rextester.com/XUQI41513) is what I've tried so far, but it returns `Delegate.CreateDelegate` method.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something like this method:

```
public static string GetMethodName<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expression) {
    if (expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Lambda || expression.Body.NodeType != ExpressionType.Call)
        return null;
    MethodCallExpression methodCallExp = (MethodCallExpression) expression.Body;
    return methodCallExp.Method.Name;
}
```

Call like this: `GetMethodName<string>(s => s.ToLower())` will return "ToLower".